# Appending two dataframes with parent column, multiple child columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes. The first dataframe is for calculating the total cost of consignment note by location and month. The second one is for calculating the total cost (maintainence + fuel) by location and month.

My code is as below:

```
def test():
    start_date = '2022-01-01'
    end_date = '2022-05-31'

  ###### First dataframe
  # Get monthly delivery log cost
    total_delivery_log_cost = monthly_delivery_log_cost_by_branch(start_date, end_date)

  # Get monthly pickup cost
    total_pickup_log_cost = monthly_pickup_log_cost_by_branch(start_date, end_date)

  # Union total monthly cost (CN)
    df = pd.concat([total_delivery_log_cost, total_pickup_log_cost])

  # Pivot
    df = df.pivot_table(index=['location'],columns =['report_month'], aggfunc = np.sum, fill_value=0)
    df.columns = df.columns.to_flat_index().to_series().apply(lambda x: x[1])
    df = df.reset_index()
    
    df.to_csv('total_CN.csv')

  ###### Second dataframe
  # Get monthly vehicle cost:
    total_maintainence_cost = monthly_maintainence_cost_by_branch(start_date, end_date)
    print(total_maintainence_cost)

  # Get monthly refuel cost:
    total_refuel_cost = monthly_refuel_cost_by_branch(start_date, end_date)
    print(total_refuel_cost)

    # Union total monthly maintainence cost
    df = pd.concat([total_maintainence_cost, total_refuel_cost])

    # Pivot
    df = df.pivot_table(index=['location'],columns =['report_month'], aggfunc = np.sum, fill_value=0)
    df.columns = df.columns.to_flat_index().to_series().apply(lambda x: x[1])
    df = df.reset_index()
    df.to_csv('total_cost.csv')
    print(df)
    
    print("Success")
```

My first dataframe looks like below (Total CN):

```
location  2022-01       2022-02   2022-03      2022-04    2022-05
   ABC        22.00       24.00      60.20        55.30     66.43
   XYZ        50.00       40.33      14.50        50.60     90.40
   XXX        10.00       21.20      22.40        23.40     22.11 
   ...         ...        ...        ....          ....       .....
```

My second dataframe looks like below (Total Cost):

```
 location    2022-01       2022-02   2022-03      2022-04    2022-05
       ABC        30.00       33.00      5.20         65.30      12.43
       XYZ        67.00       21.33      5.50         21.60      42.40
       QWE        10.00       34.20      53.40        34.40      22.11 
       ...         ...        ...        ....          ....       .....
```

While I have these two dataframes, I want to combine them to be multi-index which what I am trying to achieve so the final DF looks like:

```
                        2022-01                  2022-02              .......
location          Total CN  Total Cost     Total CN    Total Cost      .......
    ABC           22.00       30.00         24.00          33.00      
    XYZ           50.00       67.00         40.33          21.33
    XXX           10.00       0.00          21.20          0.00   
    QWE           0.00        10.00          0.00          34.20               
    ....          ....           ....          ....           .....
```

How do I achieve this?

Comment: can you share minimal reproducible example

Answer (score 1):

You can concatenate the dataframes with keys to create new dataframe with  multi-index and swap the index levels:

```
df_total_cn = pd.read_csv("total_cn.csv", index_col='location')
df_total_cost = pd.read_csv("total_cost.csv", index_col='location')

df = pd.concat([df_total_cn, df_total_cost], axis=1, keys=['total cn', 'total cost']).swaplevel(axis=1).sort_index('columns').fillna(0)
```

**OUTPUT**

```
        2022-01             2022-02             2022-03             2022-04             2022-05
        total cn total cost total cn total cost total cn total cost total cn total cost total cn total cost
location
ABC          22.0       30.0    24.00      33.00     60.2        5.2     55.3       65.3    66.43      12.43
XYZ          50.0       67.0    40.33      21.33     14.5        5.5     50.6       21.6    90.40      42.40
XXX          10.0        0.0    21.20       0.00     22.4        0.0     23.4        0.0    22.11       0.00
QWE           0.0       10.0     0.00      34.20      0.0       53.4      0.0       34.4     0.00      22.11
```

**When some of the total columns are missing**

```
df = pd.concat([df_total_cn, df_total_cost], axis=1, keys=['total cn', 'total cost']).swaplevel(axis=1)
for i in ['2022-01', '2022-02', '2022-03', '2022-04', '2022-05', ]:
    for j in ['total cn', 'total cost']:
        if j not in df[i].columns:
            df.loc[:, (i, j)] = 0
df = df.sort_index('columns').fillna(0)
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
        2022-01             2022-02             2022-03             2022-04             2022-05
        total cn total cost total cn total cost total cn total cost total cn total cost total cn total cost
location
ABC          22.0          0    24.00      33.00     60.2        5.2     55.3       65.3    66.43      12.43
XYZ          50.0          0    40.33      21.33     14.5        5.5     50.6       21.6    90.40      42.40
XXX          10.0          0    21.20       0.00     22.4        0.0     23.4        0.0    22.11       0.00
QWE           0.0          0     0.00      34.20      0.0       53.4      0.0       34.4     0.00      22.11
```

Comment: Tried your solution. While it prints correctly, when I transform it into a csv, it seperates the date like 2022-01 to two cells for total cn and total cost... Also how do I handle if the total cost for 2022-01 is all zero, it doesn't display the column at all but I need it to display all zero.

Comment: This is the nature of to_csv, It is not for visualization proposed, 2022-01 is the index for both "total cn" and "total cost". I think you are looking for to_excel. I'm not sure what you mean by "all zero", can you edit your question (or better, write a new one) with the proper example?

Comment: Thanks, I tried changing the solution that rather than reading it directly from csv (as it might not be optimized), I concat all the dataframes and pivot it and sum their respectively total cn and total cost. The only issue is I am stuck on how to group them as one index together. I posted this in another question if you can take a look: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73060238/how-to-append-two-columns-in-a-dataframe-side-by-side-in-pandas