# how to append two columns in a dataframe side by side in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe input called `df_final` that looks like below:

```
 location      2022-01   2022-02    2022-03   2022-01   2022-02  2022-03  
      AGH      2062.25   6561.43   3154.43     0        0        0
      AIM      3122.74   3277.56   3631.45     0        0        0
      AJL      1641.82   3229.49   4937.23     0        0        0
 .................
```

The first batch of months(first three column months) are actually the total cost while the last three columns are actually the total CN. My code to generate this output is like below:

```
# Get monthly delivery CN
    total_delivery_CN = monthly_delivery_CN_by_branch(start_date, end_date)
    
  # Get monthly pickup CN
    total_pickup_CN = monthly_pickup_CN_by_branch(start_date, end_date)

  # Get monthly maintainence cost:
    total_maintainence_cost = monthly_maintainence_cost_by_branch(start_date, end_date)

  # Get monthly refuel cost:
    total_refuel_cost = monthly_refuel_cost_by_branch(start_date, end_date)
    
  # Union 
    df = pd.concat([total_delivery_CN, total_pickup_CN, total_maintainence_cost, total_refuel_cost])
    print('Union')
    print(df)
    df.to_csv('df.csv')
    
  # Pivot
    df_final = df.pivot_table(index=['location'], columns = ['report_month'], aggfunc = {'total_CN' : np.sum, 'Cost' : np.sum} , fill_value=0)
    
    df_final.columns = df_final.columns.to_flat_index().to_series().apply(lambda x: x[1])
    df_final = df_final.reset_index()
    df_final.to_csv('df_final.csv')
    
    print(df_final)
```

However, I would one to merge the two total's under the same month so the final output would look like:

```
                    2022-01                  2022-02                  2022-03       
     location     Cost     total_CN      Cost     total_CN       Cost     total_CN
      AGH        2062.25     0            6561.43     0          3154.43      0                 
      AIM        3122.74     0            3277.56     0          3631.45      0               
      AJL        1641.82     0            3229.49     0          4937.23      0               
 .................
```

How do I append these two total's under the same month?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can slice df_final into two dataframes, and then you can concatenate both frames two one as we did [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73010608/18160754):

```
df_cost = df_final.iloc[:, 0:3]
df_total_cn = df_final.iloc[:, 3:6]
df = pd.concat([df_cost, df_total_cn], axis=1, keys=['cost', 'total cn']).swaplevel(axis=1).sort_index('columns').fillna(0)
print(df)


             2022-01           2022-02           2022-03
             cost total cn     cost total cn     cost total cn
location
AGH       2062.25        0  6561.43        0  3154.43        0
AIM       3122.74        0  3277.56        0  3631.45        0
AJL       1641.82        0  3229.49        0  4937.23        0
```

Comment: I see. You're hardcoding the iloc to specific number of months but what if my months are dynamic, meaning right now you're seeing January to March. What if my report is the same format but generates from january to may,etc ?

Comment: you can use the length of df_final.columns divide by 2 as a pointer: months_count = len(df_final.columns) / 2 and then  iloc[:, 0:months_count] and iloc[:, months_count:months_count * 2]

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, yea the problem is solved.

Comment: Do you know how to add subtotal to a pivot table? My current issue is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73149805/how-to-add-subtotal-based-on-size-in-pivot-table-in-pandas. I managed to concat and get the subtotal but it destroys the structure of my pivot table from multiindex to index.

Answer (score 0):

I started with the data frame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    [
        [2,3,4,0.2,0.3,0.4],
        [2,3,4,0.2,0.3,0.4],
        [2,3,4,0.2,0.3,0.4]
    ], 
    index=('AGH', 'AIM', 'AJL'),
    columns=('2022-01', '2022-02', '2022-03', '2022-01', '2022-02', '2022-03')
).rename_axis('location')
```

Which looks like

```
          2022-01  2022-02  2022-03  2022-01  2022-02  2022-03
location                                                      
AGH             2        3        4      0.2      0.3      0.4
AIM             2        3        4      0.2      0.3      0.4
AJL             2        3        4      0.2      0.3      0.4
```

This is what you're looking for:

```
def flatten(l):
    return [item for sublist in l for item in sublist]

def create_multiindex(sorted_cols):
    return pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(
        flatten([[(char, 'Cost'), (char, 'total_CN')] for char in sorted_cols])
    )

sorted_cols = sorted(set(df.columns.map(str)))
df = df[sorted_cols]
df.columns = create_multiindex(sorted_cols)
```

It yields:

```
         2022-01          2022-02          2022-03         
            Cost total_CN    Cost total_CN    Cost total_CN
location                                                   
AGH            2      0.2       3      0.3       4      0.4
AIM            2      0.2       3      0.3       4      0.4
AJL            2      0.2       3      0.3       4      0.4
```

Comment: When I run it, it gives :    ```df_final = df_final[sorted(set(df_final.columns))]
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'Period'```

Comment: @Sandeep sounds like your columns are not strings but pandas.Period objects. You can cast these as strings. Updated the answer to do this